# How does the last book end in the Uglies series?

Tags: uglies

I remember that Tally runs into the woods with her boyfriend, but why?

What events lead up to the end of the series?

Comment: Why not just read it?

Comment: So not only are you asking how it ends, but you also want a summary of the entire series leading up to the end?

Comment: I gave an answer, because I'm a big believer in answering questions, but a quick Google search would have brought up the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I have read it but its been awhile. I just wanted to know the reason why she decided to remove herself from the society. Wikipedia is just super bland and I thought someone could give me a more direct and involved answer this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fourth book of the "trilogy" starts to follow a new protagonist, and you mention Tally, I'll assume that you mean the third book, *Specials*. As per [the Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(novel)#Plot_summary) (**emphasis** mine):

> .... Eventually, Tally is taken as the last remaining Special to be "despecialized," but she resists the surgeons and breaks out with Dr. Cable's help, becoming the only true Special left. She returns to David, still waiting at the Rusty Ruins, and realizes that her other friends have all found their places in the New System. **She decides that she wishes to remain in the wild, free from surgery, and with David she will form the "New Special Circumstances," ensuring that nature is protected from humanity's excesses**.

Prior to that, she had joined up with the "Specials", also known as the Cutters, under Dr. Cable, finds that there is an injectable cure for being "Special", and deals with an authority figure who's attempting to take over using the "Special" enhancements. She foils their plot and the cure spreads, bringing people back to normal, bringing us up to the paragraph above.